# Access host filesystem in the docker compose command

Tags: docker

I have a docker-compose.yml file that starts up a bunch of containers. In the command section for one of these I want to run a command that checks if a certain file exists in the host filesystem before proceeding with the rest of the command. How could I do this?

```
My docker-compose.yml looks something like this:
 xxx:
 image: xxx
  volumes_from:
    - xxx  
   command: >
    sh -c 'while [ **CHECK IF FILE EXISTS IN HOST FILESYSTEM** ]; do     sleep 1; done && ... **REST OF COMMANDS**'
  links:
    - xxx
```

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution could be mounting the directory of the host into the docker container, in read only mode. This way you can check (for example via the bash script you suggested) if the file exist and continue with the execution.

```
xxx:
    image: xxx
    ...
    volumes:
      - /host/directory/where/file/is/:/container/directory:ro
```